# Probability / Combinatoric of fair roulette question

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In a fair roulette there are $4$ sections, numbered $1$ to $4$.

A player spins the roulette's pointer $10$ times independently.

What is the chance that the pointer stops at each one of the $4$ sections at least one?

---

My attempt:

We have symmetric distribution here, so $|\Omega|=4^{10}$.

Define: $A_i$ = the pointer stops at each one of the sections exactly $i$ times, for $i=1,2$.

We want $P(A)$, and note that $A=\cup_{i=1}^2 A_i$

Then:
For $P(A_1)$ we choose 4 places for each section out of the 10 places, then we choose 3 sections out of the 4 and arrange them with the 6 places left, so:
$$P(A_1)=\frac{\binom{10}{4}\binom{4}{3}6!}{10^4}$$

I do not know how to calculate $P(A_2)$ however, and I am not sure that what I did is correct, if not please explain me why.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: it might be easier to compute the probability of the complementary event, i.e. that there's some number that the spinner never lands on (though this approach will require some inclusion-exclusion).

Comment: Description of your approach is confusing $A_i$ definition?

Comment: Or you can use Stirling numbers of the second kind

Comment: It's impossible for the pointer to stop exactly once at each section. That's only possible if the number of spins is equal to the number of sections. Similarly, $A_2$ also cannot happen.

Comment: @VTand You are absolutely right, thank you for mentioning that!

Comment: @Sam Great approach, will try!

Comment: @Henry What is that?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind "a Stirling number of the second kind is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ objects into $k$ non-empty subsets"

Comment: If you use Stirling Number of the second kind, $S2[10,4]$ will give you number of ways to make $4$ heaps from $10$ objects. You will have to multiply by $4!$ to assign sections to these heaps.

Comment: This is a variant of the Coupon Collector's Problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

Number of ways in which the pointer lands in $3$ sections or less in all $10$ attempts:

$ \displaystyle {4 \choose 3} \cdot 3^{10} - {4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^{10} + {4 \choose 1} \cdot 1^{10}$

Subtracting it from $4^{10}$ gives number of ways in which the pointer lands in each of the sections at least once. Dividing by $4^{10}$ then gives the desired probability.

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CalculusLover you are welcome!

Comment: I don't think this is right. The number of ways in which all $10$ attempts land in $3$ sections *or less* is $ \displaystyle {4 \choose 3} \cdot 3^{10}.$ I don't get why you're excluding it landing in $2$ sections only or in $1$ section only.

Comment: @AdamRubinson I am not excluding it. I am applying P.I.E. ${4 \choose 3} \cdot 3^{10}$ overcounts cases where the pointer lands in two sections all $10$ times.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLover i could not comprehend the order of binomial coefficients , why is it not equal to $$\binom{4}{1}3^{10} -\binom{4}{2}2^{10}+\binom{4}{3}1^{10}$$

Comment: @Bulbasaur they are same. When you write ${4 \choose 1} \cdot 3^{10}$, I am assuming you are choosing one of the sections where the pointer never lands. I am instead choosing three sections where the pointer can land.